# How can I indicate statistical significance on a bar chart of mean values using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, ggpubr

I am struggling for a while to use ggplot2 for making a specific barplot.
For a gene of interest, I want to show the gene counts in my two samples.
X axis should have the samples, Y axis the mean of the counts, it should have error bars and show the result of a independent t-test, testing for a significant difference between both samples.

This is for the barplot showing the mean counts and error bars:

```
genecounts <- data.frame(
  sample = c("control", "control", "condition", "condition"),
  counts = c(7.9, 4.2, 5.2, 7.7)
)

genecounts2 <-  genecounts %>%
  group_by(sample) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(counts), sd = sd(counts))

barplot <- ggplot(genecounts2) +
  geom_bar(
    aes(x = sample, y = mean),
    stat = "identity"
    ) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(x = sample, ymax = mean + sd, ymin = mean - sd),
    width = 0.25
    ) +
  labs(y = "mean normalized counts", x = "gene name")
```

How do I add labels for significance?
I tried using ggpubr or ggsignif. All solutions that I found so far are using as a basis a data tables in which you can find the counts for all samples. But I want to do it on a barplot that only shows the mean of all samples counts. Ideas are highly appreciated!

What I thought:

```
library("ggpubr")
paircomparison <- list(c("control", "condition"))

barplot + stat_compare_means(comparisons = paircomparison)

# OR

barplot + stat_compare_means(data = genecounts, aes(x = sample, y = counts), comparisons = paircomparison)

Error in f(...) : 
  Can only handle data with groups that are plotted on the x-axis
```

It could somehow look similar to this:

[image: link]

Comment: Labels indicating the result of a test for significance between the bars, I added a picture.

Comment: And what do you want to show when there is not a significant differences (as in your case)?

Comment: preferred: n.s.

Comment: if the question is unclear or if you think, it has been answered somewhere else, please say. Looking forward to feedback / suggestions.